# wordpress advanced cache not working

Tags: wordpress

We recently updated `Word-press 3.2` to `Word-press 3.9.1`. We are facing some troubles in clearing the cache. Currently the `Word-press` advanced cache not working in latest update[ 3.9.1]. Error occurs frequently when we clearing the cache.